Use parameters based on environments for logic app in VS code
I have a requirement where there are several logic apps created in azure portal, I need to move all of them to visual studio code which I have been doing by copying the workflow.json.
So, here is what I need help with: Based on environment specification, I want to pass inputs in my workflow.json. Say, for example,  if the environment is dev, then I want to pass empty input, if it is production then I want to pass some value to the input.
I am very new to logic app and hence, no proper idea on how to do this, please guide me in achieving this.

Use appsettings for that kind of thing.

Since you mentioned workflow.json, I assume you're working with Standard Logic Apps. In this case you would typically have to deal with the following sections of the Logic App:

The app settings are stored either in the Environment variables or in the Configuration section. These settings can be either in clear text or a reference to a key vault secret:

If the app setting is a clear text value, it would need to be maintained right there in the Logic App. If it is a reference to a key vault secret, such secrets can be updated in the key vault. In this case, no changes in the Logic App would be required.
The app settings can be referenced both in the Connections and in the Parameters sections of the Logic App:


Finally, the parameters can be used in the Logic App workflows (workflow.json):

As you can see, you can keep using same workflow.json - only app settings and in some cases parameters would hold different values in different environments.
Update:
Provided that your Logic App folder has a correct structure (with connections.json, parameters.json, etc.), you only need to zip it and deploy - you can do it using ArchiveFiles@2 and AzureFunctionApp@1 tasks in DevOps pipelines. You can also update the app settings using the AzureAppServiceSettings@1 task, if necessary.
The actual implementation of deployments to different environments depends on your deployment strategy. E.g. on our project we make use of the Replace Tokens task by Guillaume Rouchon. We store app setting & parameter values for different environments in different variable groups, and during deployment the Replace Tokens task just populates JSON files with values from the relevant variable group. Then the folder is zipped and deployed. It makes it very convenient to maintain config changes in different environments separately from the code: only variables need to be updated in relevant groups. Different projects can have absolutely different deployment strategies, the possibilities are endless.

Hi, thanks a lot for letting know the workaround. I'm eager to know if this can be done even from VS code as I read few articles mentioning about parameters.json but not sure what and how the implmentation is done

@Rlaks I updated my answer adding one example of the deployment strategy. Try undertaking this gradually: first make sure you can deploy a zipped Logic App manually; when you're comfortable with the result try doing the same from DevOps pipelines; when you're comfortable with the result devise a pipeline which would cover deployments to different environments - as I mentioned the actual implementation could be different on different projects. I tried to explain briefly how we approach it.

To deploy manually, you can use az logicapp deployment source config-zip: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/logicapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-logicapp-deployment-source-config-zip

@Rlaks No worries, feel free to upvote or accept the answer if you find it useful :)

We have been following the same pattern. We download the ARM teamplate of the Logic App from Azure and use the Logic App Template Creater code by Jeffhollan. This assembly will provide a template file and parameter file. We create 3 copies of the parameter file and rename it will SUFFIX as

<>.template.parameter.DEV.json
<>.template.parameter.TEST.json
<>.template.parameter.PROD.json

We create 3 stages in the release pipeline namely DEV, TEST and PROD and use the ARM Template Deployment action. The logic app template file will not chnage however  In the action setting we use the respective paramter file specific for each environment.

